Django : Locally save an instance of a Model
Using signals, I try to track the difference between the old instance of an object and the new instance when the Model is saved.
I tried this :

But logically in the model_post_init_handler method, it's a reference of the object that is stored in __original_instance. So, instance.__original_instance.is_used and instance.is_used will always be the same.
How could I store a "snapshot" of the object when he is initiated, so that I will be able to track what is edited ?
UPDATE
The above method is functional. But it is not practical : the foreign keys are not managed and need to be managed by hand. As I will use this receiver for many models, it will be fastidious. Also, I don't like the json.loads(json.dumps()) that I've used to convert OrderedDict returned by the serializer to dict.
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Document)
def model_pre_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    model_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(sender().__serialize__(Document.objects.get(pk=instance.id)).data))
    model_dict['type'] = DocumentType.objects.get(pk=model_dict['type']['id'])
    instance.__original_instance = sender(**model_dict)


Try storing original_instance as dict. You can use instance.dict() function.

Model has no method .dict(), but I'm actually trying with Serializers. Not very practical because it doesn't manage Foreign Keys well

Please try instance.dict It will give you the dict. And later you can convert it to Model Instance

django_model_tracker library does this for you. You can check it out at https://pypi.org/project/django-model-tracker/ and check the tutorial at https://dev.to/mkalioby/tracking-database-changes-4kal

Unfortunatly, if I have understood your library, the record will be inserted even if there's no change in the fields of the instance ? If it's the case, I don't need exactly that. I need to insert an element in the historic just if one of the fields has changed.

you can do that in the save  function to check if there are changed values between self.old_state and self

Will It not lead to some performance issues to check it in the save method ? I will check that for many models. It's why I'm thinking that signals are a better option. What do you think is better ?

The performance will be close and I think the save will be a few msecs faster as there is no context switching especially, you will use the pre_save signal.

Thanks, I will try your solution. I need to think a way for it to fit with some others constraints in my project.
